# declaring variables of storage classes

Tags: c, variables

As I was coding, I was declaring the following:

```
const int a = 4;
```

Is "a" a variable that the compiler won't let me change? or would I need static const int a = 4?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

When you define `a` with `const int a = 4;`, you **should not** change `a`, but the compiler is not required to prevent you from doing so. The compiler should produce a diagnostic message if you attempt to modify `a` directly, as with `a = 5;`, but there are other ways you could try to modify `a` that the compiler will not necessarily catch, such as `* (int *) &a = 5;`. If you do this, the C standard does not define the resulting behavior. Adding `static` to the definition will not change this.

Comment: Good pointing out that it is not guaranteed.  it's not a write-protect tab on a variable, much as you might wish otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

```
const int a = 4;
```

Is a variable that the compiler won't let you change.

The static qualifier changes the way the variable behaves.  Specifically what it means is that the variable is "allocated" when the program starts execution and only deallocated when the program terminates.  In particular static class variables maintain their state independent of instantiated objects.  Static variables in functions maintain their state between function calls.  Static qualifiers on global constants are redundant in this case and are only used to determine internal/external linkage.

Comment: What are "class variables"? (The question is tagged c, not c++.)

Comment: In C, static qualifiers on global constants are not redundant, either.

Comment: I'd like to see chapter and verse on "global constants" in C also.

Comment: Given the simplicity of the question, I thought digging into how the linker handles static vs non-static was overkill :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify a when you have declared it as const.

```
const int a = 5;
a = 6;
```

Does not compile (expression must a modifiable lvalue).

Comment: Not strictly true.  You can modify it indirectly through a pointer in a way the compiler won't catch.